# Problems with laravel 5 and url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, laravel, laravel-5

Hi i'm new with laravel and i'm doing a simple blog, but i have problems with the urls.

The .htaccess changes the url:

My link:

[image: link]

when i do a click:
[image: when i do a click]

my code:

```
Route::get('/descargas', 'DescargasController@index');

public function index()
    {
        //$file= public_path(). "/descargas/guia.pdf";
        //$headers = array('Content-Type: application/pdf',);
        //return Response::download($file, 'guia_examen.pdf', $headers);
        dd("lml");
        //return view('hichat');


    }
```

The blade code:

```
<a href="{{ url('/descargas') }}" class
```

Why pass this :C

Comment: Change the VHOST entry for your localhost to serve from /blog/public.

Comment: is mod_rewrite turned on ?

Comment: yes is turned on but, is posible to manage the url without VHOST ?

Comment: Your .htaccess file please ?

Comment: Complicate your life even more... so many tutorials how to set up vhost, homestead, your own ApacheMySQLPhp stack.. anyway what kind of OS you are on?

Answer (score 1):

Your server may be configured to see the Laravel public directory as Docroot, and that means that your URL paths need not have blog/public in them as http://localhost:8082 is probably pointing the blog/public directory already.  If the paths to the js assets are working, the apache configuration may be wrong.

Comment: but not is posible to do this without virtualhost?

Comment: If you are using php artisan serve - then your DOCROOT is the public directory under the Laravel install (the Laravel directory is where artisan is located).  You do not need a vhost for php artisan serve.  Laravel handles all the routing.  Do you have a defined route for the URL blog/public?